# Why a dummy script block in html fixes css animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i inserted this line of code

```
<script>0</script>
```

in my html as adviced in some udemy answers and it indeed fixed an animations problem i had where the text instead of just coming on the center of the page, would make a small "jump" at the start and it was annoying. The script block fixed it.

Couldnt find any thread related to this.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />

    <title>Natours | Exciting tours for adventurous people</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Should fix animations flickery  -->
    <script> 
      0;
    </script>

    <header class="header">
      <div class="header__logo-box">
        <img
          src="./img/imgDestiny/destiny-logo-white.png"
          alt="Logo"
          class="header__logo"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="header__text-box">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
          <span class="heading-primary--main">Destiny</span>
          <span class="heading-primary--sub">is your only limit</span>
        </h1>

        <div class="text-box--btn">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">Discover your Fate</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
/*
COLORS:

Light green: #7ed56f
Medium green: #55c57a
Dark green: #28b485

*/

/*
COLORS2:

Light green: #10bcf0
Medium green: #556ac5
Dark green: #284db4

*/

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; /* Take border-box of the body and inherit to the universally selected elements */
}

html {
  /* font-size: 10px; For people that need to increase the font size in order to read the page, pixels are not recommended */
  font-size: 62.5%; /* % of the default 16px to get 10px*/
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* font-size: 16px; browser default */
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 3rem;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right bottom,
      rgba(15, 187, 240, 0.75),
      rgba(40, 77, 180, 0.75)
    ),
    url(../img/imgDestiny/destiny-background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  position: relative;

  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75vh);
}

.header__logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.header__logo {
  height: 8rem;
}

.header__text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-box--btn {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fixes animations shaking */
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.heading-primary--main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 6.1rem;

  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;

  /*
  animation-delay: 3s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  */
}

.heading-primary--sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2.5rem;

  animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes moveInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10rem);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateX(1rem);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(10rem);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateX(-1rem);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInBottom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(3rem);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10rem;

  transition: all 0.2s;

  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-0.3rem);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn--white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn--white:after {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn--animated {
  animation: moveInBottom 0.5s ease-out 0.75s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

What happens: https://streamable.com/0vikac
See without the script tags the text "jumps" up a bit at the start of animations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because typing a plain `0` in your script tag will generate an error which will stop the animations.

Comment: Script tag doesn't has any effect on display directly, and neither the 0 output will have to do anything. Could be that some script might be trying to find inline script tag and would causing unexpected behavior due to lack of inline script tag. Your inline script tag could be a placeholder for some script. Remaining for better reason code is need.

Comment: uhm no the animations will function as normal. i have not js script to execute since im just writing html and css. Check the recording i post on edit

Comment: @Brayden W: Why? `0` is a perfectly valid script (that doesn't do anything though).

Comment: @CherryDT: Sorry about that. I must've mixed that up with `return 0;`